# How to display only the last field?

Tags: sed, awk, cut

I used

```
cut -d " " -f 8
```

and

```
awk '{print $8}'
```

But this assumes that the 8th field is the last one, which is not always true.

How can I display the last field in a shell script?

Comment: you wrote **byte** through your question, do you really mean byte? or field/column??

Comment: Sorry; I meant field/column. Question clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ awk '{print $NF}'
```

or the funny

```
$ echo "foo bar base" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev
base
```

Comment: +1 `for (quick) answer -> got \1 upvoted -> \1 deleted -> \1 undeleted!`  good job!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** this answer is wrong now because the question changed. Move along, nothing to see here.

You can use `tail` to print a specified number of bytes from the end of the input

```
tail -c 1
```

Comment: Oh, I foolishly answered the question that was asked, not the one that was intended ;)